# When using gulp. Is there any way to suppress the 'Started' and 'Finished' log entries for certain tasks

Tags: node.js, gulp

When using gulp. Is there any way to suppress the 'Started' and 'Finished' log entries for certain tasks? I want to use the dependency tree, but I have a few tasks in the tree that I don't want logging for because they are intermediary steps that have their own logging facilities.

Comment: First i don't think you can accomplish that, and what do you mean by logging facilities? separate build servers? you could redirect the output of the build with `.exec` if that the situation..

Comment: Sorry, so basically I am using gulp as a watcher that runs tasks. Pretty standard setup. The kicker is that some of the gulp plugins output to the cli themselves. The result is that I'm left with extra lines of 'starting' and 'stopping' around every task. I understand that for most use cases this is desired, but in my case, screen real estate is key, so I'd really prefer not to have starting and stopping messages.

Comment: it really depends on task i mean, you can create an anonymous function as a gulp task and handle all output that it produces but in cases such as making use of plugins final decision is made by the plugin code if it allows options for verbosity like https://www.npmjs.org/package/gulp-watch and the `option.verbose` , of course you can use command line to pass the values for verbose level

Comment: What I want to do though, is limit the core gulp logging of things like this, which is not plugin specific:
[gulp] Using gulpfile gulpfile.js
[gulp] Starting 'browser-sync'...
[gulp] Finished 'browser-sync' after 3.59 ms
[gulp] Starting 'watch:sync'...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[UPDATE]

As of July 2014, a `--silent` option has been added to gulp (https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/commit/3a62b2b3dbefdf91c06e523245ea3c8f8342fa2c#diff-6515adedce347f8386e21d15eb775605).

This is demonstrated in @slamborne answer below, and you should favor using it instead of the below solution if it matches your use case.

[/UPDATE]

Here is a way of doing it (inside your gulpfile):

```
var cl = console.log;
console.log = function () {
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
    if (args.length) {
        if (/^\[.*gulp.*\]$/.test(args[0])){
            return;
        }
    }
    return cl.apply(console, args);
};
```

... and that will ignore EVERY message sent using gutil.log.

The trick here obviously is to inspect messages sent to console.log for a first argument that looks like "[gulp]" ([see `gulp.util.log` source code](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp-util/blob/master/lib/log.js)) and eventually ignore it entirely.

Now, this really is dirty - you really shouldn't do that without parental supervision, and you have been warned :-)

Comment: NOTE: this workaround doesn't work with gulp 4.

Answer (score 28):

You can use the `--silent` flag with the gulp CLI to disable all gulp logging.

https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/CLI.md

Comment: The user asked to disable it for single taks

Comment: The `--silent` flag has no effect. Still shows output.

Comment: @EsTeGe `gulp task --silent` is suppressing the `Started` and `Finished` log output for me. Using _node v4.2.2_, _npm 2.14.7_, and _gulp CLI 3.8.8_.

Comment: `--silent` should be the default behavior, and an option `--verbose` should exist.

Answer (score 2):

Bit late but i think it would be better to use noop from [gulp-util](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp-util) no?

```
var gutil = require('gulp-util');
// ...
gutil.log = gutil.noop;
// or
gutil.log = function() { return this; };
```

As addressed [here](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/issues/492)

Comment: NOTE: this workaround doesn't work with gulp 4.  gulp-util has been deprecated. gulp internally uses [gulplog](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulplog)