# Gulp function to print out less verbose console log message?

Tags: gulp, gruntjs

I'm new to Gulp (or Grunt) tools. I created a function to print out the `version` value in my `package.json` file, like this

```
const {dest, parallel, series, src } = require('gulp');
const semver = require('semver');

const package_json = path.join(path.dirname(__filename),'package.json');
const pkg = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(package_json));
const version = semver.parse(pkg.version);

function get_version(cb) {
  console.log(version.version);
  cb();
}
exports.get_version = get_version
```

and I get

```
$ gulp get_version -f gulpfile-version.js 
[16:07:08] Using gulpfile ~/some_path/gulpfile-version.js
[16:07:08] Starting 'get_version'...
1.4.6
[16:07:08] Finished 'get_version' after 1.91 ms
```

How can I modify my function to be less verbose and only print out the `1.4.6` string, and not the other time-stamped lines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `--silent` flag in your command to suppress the gulp logs.
Refer the doc
https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/CLI.md

Your example

```
$ gulp get_version -f gulpfile-version.js --silent
```

Comment: This works indeed. But is there any way to build this onto the task?

Comment: Yes, but i think its dirty. You can refer to this solution. https://stackoverflow.com/a/22579569/12748361